# Is it possible to get the uninterpreted command line used to invoke a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, command-line

As per the title, is it possible to get the raw command line used to invoke a ruby script?

The exact behaviour I'm after is similar to SSH when invoking a command directly:

```
ssh somehost -- ls -l
```

SSH will run "ls -l" on the server. It needs to be unparsed because if the shell has already interpreted quotes and performed expansions etc the command may not work correctly (if it contains quotes and such). This is why ARGV is no good; quotes are stripped.

Consider the following example:

```
my-command -- sed -e"s/something/something else/g"
```

The ARGV for this contains the following:

```
--
sed
-es/something/something else/g
```

The sed command will fail as the quotes will have been stripped and the space in the substitution command means that sed will not see "else/g".

So, to re-iterate, is it possible to get the raw command line used to invoke a ruby script?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y question. You're asking about "Y" when you should really be asking about "X". Please show us the code you're using, which has prompted this question. Yes, it's possible to get the command line from `ARGV`, but there are better ways of dealing with the command-line than using `ARGV`, such as using the OptionParser class.

Comment: Apologies,  I don't think I was clear enough in my question. We're already parsing opts & args using slop but we've come across this edge case and this was the only solution I could think of at 0130.  I provided the ssh example to clarify the intention.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is at the OS level.

You could try simply quoting the entire input:

```
my-command -- "sed -e\"s/something/something else/g\""
```

In Ruby, this could be used like this:

```
ruby -e "puts ARGV[0]" -- "sed -e\"s/something/something else/g\""
(output) sed -e"s/something/something else/g"
```

Or, in a file `putsargv1.rb` (with the contents `puts ARGV[1]`):

```
ruby -- "putsargv1.rb" "sed -e\"s/something/something else/g\""
(output) sed -e"s/something/something else/g"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately quoting it is not an option as it would make using the command too cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is misguided. `ssh somehost -- ls *` will expand `*` on localhost (into e.g. `ls localfile1 localfile2 localfile3`), then execute that on the remote host, with the result of lots and lots of `ls: cannot access xxx: No such file or directory` errors. `ssh` does not see the uninterpreted command line.

As you said, you would get `-es/something/something else/g` as a single parameter. That is exactly what `sed` would get, too. This is, in fact, identical to what you get if you write `-e"s/something/something else/g"` and to `"-es/something/something else/g"`, and to `-es/something/something\ else`.

Using this fact, you can use [`Shellwords.shellescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) to "protect" the spaces and other unmentionables before handing them off to an external process. You can't get the original line, but you can make sure that you preserve the semantics.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I'm not at my computer right now but the suggestion in your last paragraph sounds like it should work. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately using shellescape didn't quite mimic SSH. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Shellescape on the args worked but didn't quite mimic SSH. Take the following example (see below for test.rb contents):

```
ruby test.rb -- ls -l / \| sed -e's/root/a b c/g'
```

This will fail using the shellescape approach but succeed with SSH. I opted for manually escaping quotes and spaces. There may be some edge cases this doesn't capture but it seems to work for the majority of cases.

```rb
require 'shellwords'

unparsed = if ARGV.index('--')
  ARGV.slice(ARGV.index('--') + 1, ARGV.length)
end || []

puts "Unparsed args: #{unparsed}"

exit if unparsed.empty?

shellescaped = unparsed.map(&Shellwords.method(:shellescape)).join(" ")
quoted = unparsed.map do |arg|
  arg.gsub(/(["' ])/) { '\\' + $1 } 
end.join(" ")

puts "Shellescaped: #{shellescaped}"
puts `bash -c #{shellescaped.shellescape}`

puts "Quoted: #{quoted}"
puts `bash -c #{quoted.shellescape}`
```

Thanks for your answers :)